# Extract all data from intent without specific index or string key

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to extract data from an Intent that comes from SHARE BUTTON by other applications. Doesn't matter if it's just text or more complex data. For example I want to extract data shared from Contacts app to my app without knowing the keys that Android Contact app uses.

Is there a loop or a way to iterate through Intent, I tried using a `for` loop and going through `intent.getExtras(n)` but it's giving me null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getIntent().getExtras().get("android.intent.extra.STREAM")
getIntent().getClipData()
```

on my device this objects are:

```
getIntent().getExtras().get("android.intent.extra.STREAM") = {android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri@830027572808}"content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/2574i5f5fc0900f5c945c"

getIntent().getClipData() = {android.content.ClipData@830027557696}"ClipData { text/x-vcard {U:content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/2574i5f5fc0900f5c945c} }"
```

which are URI's if you get something simmilar so this is your contact. How to extract data from this uri is another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null){
   Log.d("EXTRAS", extras.toString());
}
```

I've updated the example so it would be easier to understand

Comment: I still cant get an example of shared Contact data from intent to my activity.

Comment: Still getting nulls. For the record mime-type is a text/x-vcard. All i want to get from it is Name, Surname and Phone numbers extracted.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable the Debugger, put a breakpoint on an instruction and see what, at the specified time the Intent extra contains.

Or you you do what you are saying and loop until you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: This is the first thing i tried but my debugger fails at start of an app on emulator. I am using Intellij IDE.